# How to package npm and python dependencies in a deb?

Tags: node.js, npm, debian, setuptools, dpkg

I am developing small desktop application with web GUI (ReactJS) and python backend (Flask). I need to pack this application to deb-package for simple distribution.

For now scheme is pretty simple: I have standard setup.py file where python dependencies are described and debian/rules which uses dh-python to parse that file and extract dependencies to debian/control (if I understand correctly):

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

export DH_VERBOSE = 1
export PYBUILD_NAME=myapp

%:
    dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild
```

All this works fine but the problem is that I need to manage npm-dependencies as well (for GUI part). I can't add something like `npm run build` as a custom build step to my setup.py since pybuild is setting proxy-server to avoid downloading of any side packages (only deb-dependencies are allowed). There are no deb-packages for my npm-dependencies and I don't want to create them myself.

So the only way I found is to add npm-dependencies (files like bootstrap.min.js, etc.) or bundle.js to git-repository, which seems bad. Is there any other way I can solve the problem?